# floating room is possible on GML?

Tags: android, game-maker

It would be possible to make this for android on game maker?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.eatheat.floatingexample 
thanks

Comment: That is a too broad question to answer with "yes" or "no" and it would require everyone to do the investigation for you. Perhaps you should just give it a go yourself and come back with specific questions and problems you encounter during your endeavors. Have a look at [How to ask a (good) question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio does not provide such features. But theoretically, you can use all features of the Android if you use native [extention](http://help.yoyogames.com/entries/30690273-Creating-A-Native-Extension-For-Android-GMS-v1-3-).